# How to make Log4j to be written in console

Tags: log4j

My console appender in Log4J writes to server.log as well as to console. How I make it write only to console?

Currently it is :

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %M (%C{1}:%L) – %m%n" />
       </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no additional file appender?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is not so. Your console appender writes only to console, but you have defined some file appender somewhere. Keep in mind, that this appender could be defined in any ancestor of a class where logging occur, including rootLogger, and it is possible to have several appenders for any element. If so, logging will occur also to this file appender.

Another possibility is to check that application and you use the same log4j configuration file. Sometimes log4j could use other configuration file than you thing of.